# Chrome loading local files in location different from the source location

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Excuse the title if it is overly complicated or using incorrect terms. 
I'm trying to test my index.html file in chrome. My directory looks something like this:

```
Test-1
  index.html
  images
    ht-icon.png
  css
    style.css
  js
    snap.svg.js
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving a failed to load net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Now I know why this is happening, but I don't know what caused it. It appears that Chrome has read my directory wrong and has placed the "images" folder as a subfolder to "css", and changed the folder to "img":

```
Test-1
  index.html
  css
    img
      ht-icon.png
    style.css
  js
    snap.svg.js
```

If I give in and just rename my folder to "img" and place it in the "css" folder the image appears without any issue. Still I do want to be able to move my folder where I want.

To help avoid confusion:

- I edit the path in style.css whenever I change things around.
- The folder name "img" was the original folder name before I changed it trying to troubleshoot some other problems. However, I've never placed it in the "css" folder.

Comment: Apparently you're incorrectly using relative paths in your css/html files e.g. missing/extra `../` in a path. Please edit the question and add the relevant parts where you reference the files.

Comment: @wOxxOm That solved it. Thank you very much!